# Filter specific user id from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We're using Google Analytic's User ID feature and would like to filter our data to exclude users with a specific user ID (in our case "DEMO").

Any suggestions on how this might be accomplished?  Or is this not possible?

Comment: Why was this down voted?  I searched the web but could find no answer and experimenting with GA I could not find an obvious solution.  Seems to me a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per default this is not possible, since the user id is not exposed via the interface and cannot be used in filters or segments (you can check the available fields for UI and API in the [Dimensions and Metric Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)).

You would have store the user id as a custom dimension, and filter by that. This will not work for data that has already been collected.